# Нажать на кнопку selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Пишу парсер и застрял на одном моменте. Вот мой код

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

slovar = {'login': 'login',
          'password': 'password'}

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://instagram.com')
time.sleep(1)
username = browser.find_element_by_name('username')
username.send_keys(slovar['login'])
password = browser.find_element_by_name('password')
password.send_keys(slovar['password'])
submit = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('form')
submit.submit()
time.sleep(3)
```

При выполнении перекидывает на другую страницу
Нужно нажать на ещё одну кнопку

```
<div class="cmbtv">
    <button class="sqdOP yWX7d    y3zKF     " "button">Не сейчас</button>
</div>
```

Как я могу нажать на кнопку не сейчас с помощью selenium?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос задан 27 минут назад. Решение в гугле ищется за 27 секунд.

```
button = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("sqdOP yWX7d    y3zKF     ")
button.click()
```

Comment: `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".sqdOP yWX7d    y3zKF     "}
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.97)`

Comment: `k = 60` ;) ...

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("sqdOP").click
```

Если нужно найти сразу несколько таких элементов, используйте не `element`, а `elements`.